# Автогруппировка строк

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Есть список в котором находится столбец с числовыми пунктами. У каждого пункта может быть подпункт. У каждого подпункта может быть свой подпункт и т.д (см. приложение 1). Глубина подпунктов определяется точкой.

Нужна помощь с кодом к appscripts для автогруппировки всех пунктов и подпунктов. Насколько я понял, это можно провернуть с помощью следующих методов: [Class Group](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/group) и [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#shiftColumnGroupDepth(Integer)).

Алгоритм создания групп, скорее всего, будет строится на количестве точек в подпункте. Если в пункте на следующей строке точек больше, то он попадает в подгруппу для предыдущего пункта и т.д.

В результате, конечная группировка будет выглядеть следующим образом (см. приложение 2)

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Ну, а код-то где? Или за вас и пальцы загибать надо?

Comment: @contributorpw Программированием не занимался и JavaScript в частности, не изучал. Но нужно решить такую задачку. Подобный вопрос на stackoverflow не находил. Конечно я начал читать уроки по JS и, возможно, решение этой задачки - вопрос времени, но времени для решения не так много.

Comment: @contributorpw Если не код, то может есть идея на счёт алгоритма? Возможно то, что я описал не идеально и есть другой вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Основной алгоритм должен быть таким:

- Взять все
- Сортировать
- Идти по дереву, исключая элементы без детей
- Формализовать дерево для метода группировки
- Снять все текущие группировки
- Применить новые группировки

В идеале при формализации нужно для каждой группы создать запрос вида

```
{
    "updateDimensionGroup": {
        "dimensionGroup": {
            "range": {
                "sheetId": <sheet_guid>,
                "dimension": "ROWS",
                "startIndex": 2,
                "endIndex": 5
            },
            "collapsed": true,
            "depth": 1
        },
        "fields": "collapsed"
    }
}
```

Запросы на обновление нужно отправлять пакетным методом.